# Проблема с подменю при наведении курсора

Tags: php, css, list, css-animation, hover

**Я когда навожу мышь на меню, то подменю открывается, но при этом оно перекрывается видео и, следовательно, скрывается за ним. Как вывести подменю "на показ"?**

Это вместе с видео[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
А это без него [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Пожалуйста, задавая вопрос приводите неработающий фрагмент **кода**. Здесь вам помогут найти и исправить **конкретную** ошибку, а за вёрсткой сайта по макетам вам на другой ресурс.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Необходимо использовать свойство css:  z-index
CSS

.menu{
position:relative;
z-index:10; 
    }

.videoblock{
position:relative;
z-index:5;  }

HTML
`<div>
  <ul  class="menu">
    <li>Menu</li>
    <li>Menu</li>
    <li>Menu</li>
  </ul>
  <div class="videoblock">Video</div>
</div>`

Comment: А как "голубизну" убрать по краям?:)

Comment: Какую глубизну? можете более конкретно сказать?

Comment: Как на 2 картинке

Comment: Я навожу а она голубой подсветкой высвечивает весь список

Comment: Хорошо бы увидеть код меню, но думаю как то связанно с outline

попробуй так
.menu{
outline:none;
}

если конечно при hover не прописанно border-color или box-shadow